# Combining two uint8_t as uint16_t

Tags: c

I have the following data

```
uint8_t d1=0x01; 
uint8_t d2=0x02;
```

I want to combine them as `uint16_t` as

```
uint16_t wd = 0x0201;
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use bitwise operators:

```
uint16_t wd = ((uint16_t)d2 << 8) | d1;
```

Because:

```
 (0x0002 << 8) | 0x01 = 0x0200 | 0x0001 = 0x0201
```

Comment: Yes, it is. `d2` needs to be cast first (which the edited post takes care of.)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Oh, yes, I've forgotten it. Thanks.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore & JonathanGrynspan Not neccessarily, since `d2` is first promoted to `int` (which is at least 16 bit). But Ok, it could still be UB if `int` was really just 16 bit on his platform and `(int)d2 << 8` would overflow the non-negative `int` range.

Comment: I don't see how the cast would improve anything. Suppose that uint16_t has lower conversion rank than `int`, then you have solved nothing with the cast, the left operand would still be implicitly promoted to (signed) int. But since there is no way that could yield a negative value, the behavior of this code and the original one is always well-defined.

Comment: My answer takes care of that too.

Comment: @Lundin: If `uint16_t` has lower conversion rank than `int`, then the full range of `uint16_t` fits in `int`, so working in `int` is fine.

Comment: @ChristianRau Yes it may be promoted to int but it may not be a negative value. C11 6.5.7/3: `"The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand.". C11 6.5.7/4: "... E1 << E2..."  "If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2^E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value;" It is only UB if the value is negative.

Comment: @R.. Indeed, that was what I was trying to sell :)

Comment: @Lundin Of course `(int)d2` can never be negative, but `(int)d2 << 8` doesn't neccessarily need to be representable with a 16-bit `int` (in practice if `d2>=0x80`). Then this would indeed be UB (in the practical example most likely resulting in a negative number, but theoretically UB).

Comment: @ChristianRau Ok now I understand what you were concerned about. I only looked at this specific example where we have `(int)0x02 << 8` which is always well-defined. From a general programming point-of-view, you are correct.

Comment: Whether or not promotion to `int` makes the cast redundant, I would always prefer to see code like this - it's effectively a 'comment' of intent. But @R.. gives an answer that any optimizing compiler will generate efficient (e.g., shift) instructions, with no issues of rank / conversion.

Answer (score 16):

The simplest way is:

```
256U*d2+d1
```

Comment: Aw. Now we really have a use case for bitwise operations and you still stick to boring arithmetics. ;)

Comment: `<<8` and `*256` are identical operations except that the former has undefined behavior in more cases and thus is usually undesirable. There's hardly ever a reason to use the `<<` or `>>` operators unless the right-hand operand is variable (in which case you have a nice exponentiation operator).

Comment: Yeah, that comment was of rather humorous nature.

Comment: How is this answer ranking working? Why does this always appear at the bottom of the page???

Answer (score 11):

This is quite simple. You need no casts, you need no temporary variables, you need no black magic.

```
uint8_t d1=0x01; 
uint8_t d2=0x02; 
uint16_t wd = (d2 << 8) | d1;
```

This is always well-defined behavior since d2 is always a positive value and never overflows, as long as `d2 <= INT8_MAX`.

(INT8_MAX is found in stdint.h).

Comment: ... except when it's *not* 0x7F (see 5.2.4.2)

Comment: @modifiablelvalue Emphasis on _in practice_. All sane implementations use wchar_t for larger integers if that is your concern. If your concern is one's complement or sign & magnitude CPUs, then please let me know where to buy them because I want one too!

Comment: @Lundin Please read 5.2.4.2.1p2 and your compiler's manual... I'm sure there's some switch to switch chars to *unsigned* types, since this is a very common practise. Furthermore, please note that DSP processors commonly define CHAR_BIT as 16 or 32.

Comment: @Lundin: Since `uint8_t` exists by assumption, `CHAR_BIT` is 8. And `CHAR_MAX` is not in practice always 0x7f. There are plenty of systems where plain `char` is an unsigned type.

Comment: @R. Indeed, how silly of me. This code would break if CHAR_BIT were anything other than 8. Note that there's the `-funsigned-char` switch for gcc...

Comment: `INT8_MAX` is 127. It's true that `d2<<8` can be proven not to overflow when `d2<=127`, but the reason is that `INT_MAX` is required to be at least 32767 but not required to be any larger.

Comment: The down-side of stackoverflow's model is that most of this discussion is now rendered rubbish due to an edit of the original post. Providing INT_MAX == 32767, INT8_MAX is the ceiling value by coincidence. When INT_MAX >= 32768, INT8_MAX is meaningless.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue This answer was never about character types anyhow. As long as d2 <= INT8_MAX, it has no chance of getting shifted into the sign bits after it has been promoted to int.

Comment: @Lundin The danger isn't necessarily *shifting into the sign bits*; *Using a value that can't be represented as an `int`, in an expression that has `int` type* seems like a more appropriate description for this undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Lundin I agree with *modifiable lvalue*. You may be preventing the correct problem, but with the wrong means. Instead of suggesting a restriction of the input types' range (why should I constrain my `uint8_t`s to 7-bit numbers, you think I used `uint8_t`s out of no reason?) you should rather suggest the usage of the correct output type (if the need arises). You only describe a symptom of the actual problem, which might be misleading for those not aware of the actual source of UB (the possible `int` overflow, which is not directly related to the range of `d2`).

Answer (score 3):

```
(uint16_t)((d2 << 8) + (d1 & 0x00ff))
```