# Combining uint8_t, uint16_t and uint8_t

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have three values, `uint8_t`, `uint16_t` and `uint8_t` in that order. I am trying to combine them to one `uint_32` without losing the order. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249791) question from here, but I got stuck with the `uint_16` value in the middle.

For example:

```
uint8_t v1=0x01;  
uint16_t v2=0x1001;
uint8_t v3=0x11; 

uint32_t comb = 0x01100111;
```

I was thinking about spitting `v2` into two separate uint8_t:s but realized there might be some easier way to solve it.

My try:

```
v2 = 0x1001;
a = v2 & 0xFF;
b = v1 >> 8;
first = ((uint16_t)v1 << 8) | a;
end = ((uint16_t)b << 8) | v3;

comb = ((uint32_t)first << 16) | end;
```

Comment: there's shift operations, there's memcpy, and there's placement new, to name a few

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be your *nestedly* implied and as one-liner written transformation:

```
uint32_t comb = ((uint32_t)v1 << 24) | (((uint32_t)v2 << 8) | v3);
```

Basically, you have the 8 | 16 | 8 building the 32bit-sized type. To shift the first one and put at the head, you would need to cast to 32bit and use `24` (32-8). Then OR the next ones whilst shifting, i.e. placing at the right offset and the rest filling with zeros and casting respectively.

You use OR for the obvious reasons of not losing any information.

Comment: Neat, thank you. I added my solution on question but this is so much visually better than my messy one!!