# How do I combine two arrays of 8 bits each (binary number strings into one single string with 16 bits? (arduino, shift registers)

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, c-strings, shift-register

In Arduino, I'm trying to combine the 8-bit binary numbers/strings from two PISO (parallel in - series out) shift registers into one 16-bit binary string. The binary numbers stored on a variable (switchVar1) with the shiftIn() command on Arduino `switchVar1 = shiftIn(dataPin, clockPin);`
switchVar1 was first defined by `byte switchVar1 = 72;`.
I'm doing this so I can then read the binary string with the switch() function and do different combinations as I have 16 contacts/buttons where different combinations of all the 16 buttons will be defined so I need a string of 16-bit binary number.
Basically, I'm asking how to turn two 8-bit binary number arrays into one single array.
Keep in mind, I'm completely new to c++ so there might be some basic solution that I probably didn't think of.

Comment: something like `unsigned char src[2]; unsigned int dst; dst = ((unsigned int)src[0] << 8) | src[1];`?

Comment: @MikeCAT  Shouldn't you be using `uint16_t` instead of unsigned int?

Comment: Is the type of both inputs `byte`, and what is the desired output type? `std::uint16_t`?

Comment: @AndyG the only UB I see is if `src[2]` wasn't initialized. `uint16_t` reduces wasted space if the `unsigned int` is more than 16 bits.

Comment: @AndyG I do not see any violations to strict aliasing rule in this snippet.

Comment: Also, Arduino is 2-byte integers, so `unsigned int` would be an alias with `uint16_t`

Comment: Try use this: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/33606/how-can-i-concatenate-multiple-byte-arrays-into-one-array I hope I helped you!

Comment: I've implemented a similar (?) function to concatenate bytes. Check the implementation of the function `concat_bytes` in [this header file](https://github.com/amanuellperez/mcu/blob/master/src/atd/atd_bit.h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It got figured out with thanks to everyone commenting. So I just did it like:
`switchVar1 = shiftIn(dataPin, clockPin); switchVar2 = shiftIn(dataPin2, clockPin2); uint16_t switchVariable = switchVar1 | (switchVar2<<8);`
as in I first created two, byte files and "shifted" the numbers on one (switchVar2) 8 steps to the left (to be literal) (with the `<<` bitwise operator) and added both together with the bitwise OR operator (the pipe symbol |) in one `uint16_t` variable type. Then I just read all the combinations with the `switch() case` command.
(Also, I'm stupidly new to programming languages in general, and saying "arrays" was my bad.)

Answer (score 0):

You should check out how bitwise operations and bitmask work. You'll find here a way to do it.

[Combining two uint8_t as uint16_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249791/combining-two-uint8-t-as-uint16-t/15249800)